# Как с помощью Python вытащить из файла числа, которые находятся перед и после определенного текста

Tags: python

Есть файл (10 мб), из которого нужно вытащить числа, которые идут перед и после определенного текста, затем эти числа скопировать в третий файл. Число, которое находится перед текстом, назвать в третьем файле name1, число которое находится после текста, назвать name2.

Вот пример из файла:

```
    <record>
        <integer id="database_table_type" value="1"/>
        <large id="db_unique_id" value="77541356759907188"/>
        <integer id="version" value="57854321"/>
        <unsigned id="property" value="1348695145"/>
        <record id="new_value">
            <unsigned id="id" value="1853322860"/>
            <integer id="Ttea" value="602"/>
        </record>
        <record id="odvl">
            <unsigned id="id" value="1868854892"/>
            <integer id="Ttea" value="618"/>
        </record>
    </record>
    <record>
```

Нужно сделать поиск по такому такому тексту:

```
                                                 "/>
        <integer id="version" value="57854321"/>
        <unsigned id="property" value="1348695145"/>
        <record id="new_value">
            <unsigned id="id" value="1853322860"/>
            <integer id="Ttea" value="
```

и вытащить числа которые в начале и конце от этого текста.

В данном примере:

77541356759907188 - это число перед текстом.

602 - это число после текста.

Нужно записать их в новый файл так:

name1: 77541356759907188

name2: 602

Почему надо совершать поиск именно так, а не например просто по "db_unique_id" и "Ttea", потому что тогда охватятся ненужные числа, потому что если в "property" value="1348695145" и "id" value="1853322860" будут другие значения,то рядом стоящие числа не нужны.

---

Понимаю, что выгдядит всё это непонятно. Попробую на другом примере объяснить.

Представьте, что есть файл, в котором очень много таких вариантов строк:

"число"первыйвариант"число"

"число"второйвариант"число"

"число"третийвариант"число"

"число"первыйвариант"число"

и тд.

Нужны те числа, которые располагаются в кавычках перед и после "первыйвариант".

Например:

"111"первыйвариант"222"

"333"второйвариант"444"

"555"третий вариант"666"

"777"первыйвариант"888"

Результат:

name1: 111

name2: 222

name1: 777

name2: 888

Comment: ничего не понятно. Объясни потолковее, что нужно найти и как именно известно, что нужно найти именно это.

Comment: НУЖНЫ числа которые идут следом за "db_unique_id" и первым после него "Ttea". НО! Если в "property" не это число "1348695145", или в "id" не это число "1853322860". Тогда db_unique_id и Ttea не нужны. Не знаю как ещё объяснить. понимаю что тяжело понять. думаю лучше сделать поиск как я написал и от этого поиска первое и последнее числа вытащить, если это возможно конечно

Comment: что-бы вас поняли рекомендую взять и аккуратно расписать алгоритм тех действий, которые вы хотите выполнить.  Не просто набор каких-то предложений, а именно алгоритм. Может потом и вопрос не придется задавать, а может -  если в этом алгоритме выявятся ошибки -  вам помогут его исправить.

Comment: Эникейщик, я для вас добавил в конце поста другие примеры, думаю, так будет понятнее. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предварительно нужно установить библиотеку lxml, типа
`pip install lxml`
Важно чтобы входной файл был "исправен", т.е. теги закрыты. Слишком маленький кусок файла, чтобы понять структуру.

```
from lxml import etree

with open('fm.xml') as f:
    s = f.read()

root = etree.XML(s)
res = ''
for el in root.xpath('//record/unsigned [@id="property"]'):
    if el.get('value') == '1348695145':                             #Выбираем "property" value="1348695145"
        t = el.find('..//large')
        z1 = t.values()[1]

        for t1 in el.xpath('..//record [@id="new_value"]'):
            if len(t1):
                if t1[0].get('value') == '1853322860':              #Выбираем  "id" value="1853322860"
                    z2 = t1[1].get('value')
                    res += f'name1:{z1} \nname2:{z2} \n'

with open('out.txt', 'w') as of:
    of.write(res)
```

Comment: Вы лучший) всё получилось, спасибо вам большое

Comment: А интересно, на примере, которые привел ТС, вот этом ""111"первыйвариант"222"

"333"второйвариант"444"

"555"третий вариант"666"

"777"первыйвариант"888",   этот алгоритм сработает? А ведь должен, раз ТС привел его нам в качестве ПРИМЕРА.

Comment: Краткий алгоритм, ищем "property" value, в найденной секции ищем id="new_value" и если "id" value="1853322860" результаты записываем в файл.